# POJO as parameter for insert in Mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I have this Domain Object called UserDTO

here is my mapper.xml file config

```
<insert id="insertUser" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id" parameterType="com.myapp.dto.UserDTO">
    insert into
    tblusers(username,password,email,phone,role,is_active,security_question,securtiy_answer,first_name,last_name)
    values(#{username},#{password},#{email},#{phone},#{role,typeHandler=com.greenflight.typehandlers.StringArrayListTypeHandler},#{is_active},#{security_question},#{securtiy_answer},#{first_name},#{last_name})
</insert>
```

But this is throwing Exception like this

```
  Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error getting generated key or setting result to parameter object. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException: Error attempting to get column #1 from result set.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : asdfds
### The error may involve org.mybatis.myapp.Mapper.insertUser-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: insert into   tblusers(username,password,email,phone,role,is_active,security_question,securtiy_answer,first_name,last_name)   values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error getting generated key or setting result to parameter object. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException: Error attempting to get column #1 from result set.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : asdfds
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:200)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:185)
    at com.greenflight.dao.UserDAO.CreateNewUser(UserDAO.java:98)
```

I have gone through the documents of mybatis and was not able to find good example on how to send Domain objects as parameters .

can anybody show me the solution

Answer (score 0):

How you have implemented in CreateNewUserDAO method in UserDAO.I think for Phone number you are giveing wrong value (May be setting wrong value).

## {phone}

Comment: that's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to insert the record after changing the mapper file like this

I changed this

```
<insert id="insertUser" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id" parameterType="com.greenflight.dto.UserDTO">
    insert into
    tblusers(username,password,email,phone,role,is_active,security_question,securtiy_answer,first_name,last_name)
    values(#{username},#{password},#{email},#{phone},#{role,typeHandler=com.greenflight.typehandlers.StringArrayListTypeHandler},#{is_active},#{security_question},#{securtiy_answer},#{first_name},#{last_name})
</insert>
```

into

```
<insert id="insertUser"  parameterType="com.greenflight.dto.UserDTO">
    insert into
    tblusers(username,password,email,phone,role,is_active,security_question,securtiy_answer,first_name,last_name)
    values(#{username},#{password},#{email},#{phone},#{role,typeHandler=com.greenflight.typehandlers.StringArrayListTypeHandler},#{is_active},#{security_question},#{securtiy_answer},#{first_name},#{last_name})
</insert>
```

The parameters

```
   useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id"
```

works for **HashMap** but not for POJO don't know why

Comment: This inserts a record, but does not return inserted record id, which was the initial usage of `useGeneratedKeys` and `keyProperty`.

Comment: In that case you can use HashMap